# scp from remote to remote host groovy

Tags: groovy, scp

Hey I was wondering if its possible to use the scp from one remote host to another in a groovy script. I tried doing it but got the error:

```
: Copying from a remote server to a remote server is not supported.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp.execute(Scp.java:229)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at scp.run(scp.groovy:7)
```

Is there any way around this? I wanted to avoid copying the files to my local machine since the files are big and it will waste time

Comment: can you instruct one server to copy? like `ssh server scp server2:file .` ?

Comment: ok i never though about that. i will surely look into it. i should be able to do it, just a matter of learning how now. can you provide any hints on doing it?

Comment: when i ssh into my machine and then run the scp command i get a permission denied? im guessing we cant do this either?

Comment: i'd would make copying between the servers work.  especially, if your two servers are connected fast and you are instructing from some crappy connection (e.g. DSL).